# How to use DelegatingHandler in .net core for remove property from Response in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, delegatinghandler

**How to use DelegatingHandler in .net core for remove property from Response in asp.net core?**

if logged-in user is not Admin then how to remove some property from response in API?

Comment: What type of response you are return?HttpResponseMessage?And what parameter you want to remove.

Comment: Json object is return from API. Want to remove azure connectionString from response.